# how to update a variable in form1 from form2 using winforms

Tags: winforms

I have kind of a status field in form1 to be updated from different forms.

am coming back to winforms after few years,  I need a reminder please, in c# .
form1 has a var string lets say (is Text called status)

how would you update status field in  form1 from different forms

thanks.

Comment: This question pops up every day. Search stock overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the Status field (suppose this is a Label) in Form1 like below:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Label _statusLabel;

    public static string Status
    {
        set
        {
            _statusLabel.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to set the status field from different forms like below:

```
Form1.Status = "PUT DESIRED STATUS HERE"
```

**Edit:**
You can find **StatusStrip** (System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip) in the toolbox under "**Menus & Toolbars**" tab. After adding it to your form, you'll see a dropdown icon from where you have to add **ToolStripStatusLabel** (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel). Then just rename the "_statusLabel" with the newly added one.

If you need further assistance, feel free to ask !

Comment: thanks Wasif Hossain, i beleive you have to pass form1 to forms where you want to display status ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to fulfill your need. Please have a look at it!

Comment: thank you wasif for your help, the project is now in another department,